# How to debug DVC in pycharm

Tags: dvc

I know Kedro allows debugging using Pycharm. Is there some way to wrap DVC terminal commands to allow stepping through code in the Pycharm debugger?

Comment: Do you mean attaching / making breakpoints in some code that is being run with `dvc repro` or `dvc exp run`, to some DVC pipeline stage? (could you please improve/clarify your question, add a link to Kedro if they have something on it).

Comment: Yes that is correct. This is an example of the Kedro functionality - SequentialRunner().run() https://dev.to/waylonwalker/using-kedro-in-scripts-6l2

Comment: tbh, I don't think there is an easy way to do. May be it's possible to parametrize the pipeline and run each `cmd` via debugger (the way PyCharm / VS Code do). I haven't tried it. Would it be easier to run a command yourself in this case (a specific step of the pipeline)?

Comment: Sure, can do that. Would be nice to have a Runner. Maybe throw it in the backlog as an idea.